# Should Worldbuilding set up a Twitter account?

Tags: discussion, community, twitter

A number of Stack Exchange sites have their own Twitter accounts, which are controlled by a bot that tweets hot questions.

Some sites on the network have decided they don't like this, and have created their own independent Twitter account for the site, which is controlled by a group of humans who tweet questions that have caught the community eye, retweets of other comments about the site, and other on-topic links.

Should Worldbuilding become part of this latter category? With a Twitter account of our own, we could promote the site, promote the blog, engage with our community on another platform, etc etc. It could be controlled by a group of users (or the moderators, *if* they have the time and inclination to do it), which is arguably better than a bot.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

This sounds like a good idea.  Giving a moderator access sounds like a reasonable idea, but in general, this is something that can be handled by the community without diamond intervention.  So if a moderator wants to actively participate then great, but, like the blog, this wouldn't be an official thing and can thus be done by anybody.

Mi Yodeya has a curated Twitter account (also an SE-supplied bot).  There are, I think, three people with access to the account, though 90% of the work is done by one (non-moderator) user.  There needs to be at least one person who's enthusiastic enough to keep it up.

Occasionally retweeting other worldbuilding-related content not from our site and users is an important tool in the "building visibility" toolbox.  So someone with access to the account should be following other Twitterers who post such material.

Answer (score 7):

I think that's a good idea. It requires a group of 3 to 5 active users. I think it would be preferable to have at least one mod in the team. We could repost the blog posts, post hots or challenging questions. And maybe engage further in the worldbuilding community of twitter.

Twitter is always a rather nice way to have headlines and short stories promoted around.